# Heroku psql lists hundreds of weird databases

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

So when I go into "heroku pg:psql" and type `\l` I get this:

[image]

What's the deal with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On dev and basic plans, your postgresql database is shared with others on the server.
Therefore, you are not the only one on this server, there are other users.

These databases you're seeing are the other users' databases.
You can't access them. But you can know they are here.

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying!  I was a bit spooked for a moment and immediately checked my creditcard! :)